# ngx-bootstrap tooltip container class is not working

Tags: css, angular, tooltip, z-index, ngx-bootstrap

[image]

I am using tooltip from ngx-bootstrap with this code

```
<button tooltip="Add column before" container='body' placement='bottom' containerClass='tooltipClass'> 
    <i class="plus"></i>
</button>
```

and code for tooltipClass is

```
.tooltipClass{
  z-index:100;
  color:green
}
```

The tooltip is beneath the row Numbers and that is because of the z-index on rowNo. but I am adding greater z-index to the tooltip but the class is not getting added to it.
Any ideas what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place `.tooltipClass` class in the root style-file it will work!

Comment: the z-index property of it is still ain't working

Comment: it's working nicely after I added !important to the property. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was hitting this same issue, but the solutions above weren't working. Updating the global scss variables of ngx-bootstrap was how I fixed it.

This updates your inner tooltip.

```
.tooltip-inner {
  background-color: #333 !important;
  color: green !important;
}
```

This updates your arrow depending on position.

```
.bs-tooltip-bottom .arrow::before{
  border-bottom-color: #333;
}
```